# Azure SQL Database not letting me create a Database Master Key

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I created an Azure SQL Database `AzureSQLTestDb` in an Azure subscription. I can connect to this db using `SSMS` with my Azure SQL Admin login, as well as with my Azure AD account. I can run queries on it, as well. But following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-a-database-master-key?view=sql-server-ver15), from MS Azure team, when I try to create a `Master key` as follows, it gives me the error shown below. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how can we resolve the issue?

**Remarks**: I know the above linked article mentions `CONTROL permission` required. But I am the one who created the db and the Azure SQL server.

```
 -- Creates the master key.
  -- The key is encrypted using the password "23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe".  
  CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe';
```

**Error**:

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> User does not have control permission to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue with the permissions.

As per this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions), **you need `CONTROL` permission on the database to create the master key.**

You can GRANT CONTROL permission using below command:

`GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::<dtabase:name> TO <user_name>`

[image]

If the user already have CONTROL permission, try the ALTER command to create a new database master key and reencrypts the keys below it in the encryption hierarchy.

`ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe';`

[image]